# Ruby, use of '?' - db or model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I love using the ? for boolean fields, e.g, for 'animals' table "alive?" is very obvious.
Where do I define this?  Do I name the db field with it when creating the table migration(don't think so).
Or is it automatic for boolean fields or do I have a little method in the active record model class for animals that says something like def alive?  if alive then true else false end ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails automatically generates a method ending in a `?` for each of the fields in a model.
Some examples:

```
Animal #=> Animal(id: integer, alive: boolean, name: string)
a = Animal.new

a.alive #=> nil
a.alive? #=> false
a.alive = true
a.alive? #=> true

a.name #=> nil
a.name? #=> false
a.name = "Giraffe"
a.name? #=> true
```

Also note that you can easily define your own `?` methods:

```
class Animal
  def young?
    created_at > 1.day.ago
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is automatic for all boolean fields in ActiveRecord.

As an extra nicety, I like to name boolean fields with an `is_` prefix. `is_alive`, giving you `is_alive?`.

Comment: nice but personal standards when sharing code are a nightmare for all to use and maintain.

Comment: Borrowed straight from Ruby and Rails itself. `is_a?`, 'is_missing?', 'is_eos?', etc.

Comment: yes they are just like ruby's method naming which is great.  They follow the same standards and format which is also great.  I still really believe however that: personal standards when sharing code are a nightmare for all to use and maintain. Please ponder :)  If you can get them into ruby core no problem.